# How to eliminate multiple instances of a substring from a string

Tags: ruby

I got a string

```
str = "<strong><strong>HI</strong></strong>".
```

I want to eliminate duplicate instances of `<strong>` and `</strong>` to get `<strong>HI</strong>`.

There could potentially be more than two instances.

I tried to use `squeeze('<strong>')`, but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: _"I tried to use squeeze('<strong>') but it doesn't seem to do the job"_ – `squeeze` is not the right tool, neither is `gsub` (or any other regex based method). You probably want a HTML parser (unless your strings are really that trivial).

Comment: @Stefan: dare we link to _the_ answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

you could do this:

```
str = "<strong><strong>HI</strong></strong>"
str.gsub('<strong><strong>', '<strong>').
    gsub('</strong></strong>', '</strong>') # => "<strong>HI</strong>"
```

Comment: There could be more than 2 instances. How can I handle that?

Comment: Run this over and over, until string stops changing, for example. Or use a regex match group with `+` quantifier.  Or maybe something else.

Comment: Sergio, I must remember that last suggestion in your comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, very useful. I use it all the time :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
str = "<strong><strong>HI</strong></strong>"

p str[/<.*?>/]+ str[/>([^<]*)<\//,1]+str[/<\/.*?>/]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be to use regex to get the desired result.

```
str.match(/<[a-z]+>[a-zA-Z]+<[\/a-z]+>/)
=> #<MatchData "<strong>HI</strong>">
```

Comment: what if  `"<data_node><data_node>HI</data_node></data_node>".`

Comment: You just have to update regex. I have covered what OP asked.

Comment: His question automatically implicates that anything can come inside the node

Comment: I don't think so, OP has tried `squeeze('<strong>')` which means he specifically looks for it. Otherwise let OP update the question.

Comment: When he say `squeeze('<strong>')` he would do something like this `squeeze('<data_node>')` as well, he has given an example

Comment: Look at my answer, it covers all the possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done multiple ways, one of which is using `gsub`, like this:

```
str
  .gsub(/(<strong>)+/, '<strong>')
  .gsub(/(<\/strong>)+/, '</strong>')
```

The first `gsub` replaces one or more consecutive instances of `<strong>` with one `<strong>`, and the second `gsub` replaces one or more consecutive instances of `</strong>` with one `</strong>` (note the `/` in the regular expression part needs to be escaped).

It's worth noting that this approach does not ensure there are a matched number of opening and closing `<strong>` tags.